# Failed at the jsx@0.1.0 start script - Terminal issue

Tags: reactjs, npm, terminal

When I try to run the npm start command for a new react app, I'm left with the below message:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! jsx@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the jsx@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Dylan/.npm/_logs/2020-11-09T21_07_05_144Z-debug.log
```

I've tried multiple debug commands and googled solutions (none worked). Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the full output

Comment: There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-loader": "8.1.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-loader was detected higher up in the tree:

  /Users/Dylan/node_modules/babel-loader (version: 7.1.5)